# Bypass eval() T_USE parse error

Tags: php, namespaces, eval

So basically I want to create multiple PrestaShop modules. There will be occasions where couple of modules will be active one same shop. The problem is that I want to use differently defined class 'MyTools' in both modules.

That would cause class redefinition error. My solution was to use namespaces:

```
<?php

require_once('classes/MyTools.php');
use Module1\MyTools;

class Module1 extends Module
{
```

And the other module:

```
<?php

require_once('classes/MyTools.php');
use Module2\MyTools;

class Module2 extends Module
{
```

MyTools classes are different here: only the used functions are kept, some functions might be update. So I cannot use the same class for all modules, also that would be not possible.

Now this code works well, except for the fact that '`use`' statement cannot be use when using eval(); That is exactly my problem, because PrestaShop uses eval() while rebuilding and checking module indexes and changes:

```
// If class does not exists, we include the file                                                                                  
if (!class_exists($module, false))                                                                                                
{                                                                                                                                 
    // Get content from php file                                                                                                     
    $filepath = _PS_MODULE_DIR_.$module.'/'.$module.'.php';                                                                          
    $file = trim(file_get_contents(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$module.'/'.$module.'.php'));                                                     
    if (substr($file, 0, 5) == '<?php')                                                                                              
        $file = substr($file, 5);                                                                                                       
    if (substr($file, -2) == '?>')                                                                                                   
        $file = substr($file, 0, -2);                                                                                                   

    // If (false) is a trick to not load the class with "eval".                                                                      
    // This way require_once will works correctly                                                                                    
    if (eval('if (false){   '.$file.' }') !== false)                                                                                   
        require_once( _PS_MODULE_DIR_.$module.'/'.$module.'.php' );                                                                     
    else                                                                                                                             
        $errors[] = '...';  
}
```

Is there any way to bypass this statement without parse error for T_USE?

```
if (eval('if (false){   '.$file.' }') !== false)
```

Error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in  in \classes\module\Module.php(1096) : eval()'d code on line 8
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your class with additional require. Put your content to other_file.php and include it in module file.

Or wrap your code with eval inside module file. : ^)

Comment: Wrapping something with eval() ? :D No thx. Putting my code in another file is also an ugly solution, I'd have two files instead of one and that would be mess. Module's file structure is clearly defined :/

Comment: @GytisŠk, it's ugly architecture. Solution follows architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they do the eval as a way to do a syntax check before including the file. I think it might be best to just strip out the use statement. As it is not executed it does not matter that the namespace cannot be found. After syntax validation is ok, it does a require, so for the workings of the application it does not matter that use was stripped during syntax check.

perhaps something like:

```
$file = preg_replace('/\n[\s\t]*?use\s.*?;/', '', $file);
```

will replace use statement as long as it is placed on a new line.

Comment: I can the way of your solution, but I will not modify/override core method. Also, if multiple modules attempted to do an override, PrestaShop wouldn't allow it.

Comment: Honestly... in that case i would either get rid of PrestaShop or deal with ugly code. As you can/will not modify the code code you are bound to this check. So basically you have 3 solutions:
Modify core code, replace the core by another software package, deal with it and write ugly code (either without use or by wrapping it like sectus said). Otherwise you are attempting to paint the mona lisa with fingerpaint.

Comment: It's not a 'must' do thing, so I'm probably just going to call full (qualified?) names. Not the first time PS disappoints me (all of us) :)